# How to pass a handler to onClick with Typescript and material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to pass a function that returns another function to material UI's onTouchTap event:

```
<IconButton
   onTouchTap={onObjectClick(object)}
   style={iconButtonStyle} >
      <img alt={customer.name} className="object-img" src={object.avatarSrc} />
</IconButton>
```

But I keep running into the following error:

```
Type '{ onTouchTap: Function; style: CSSProperties; tooltip: string; children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<IconButton> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> ...'.
```

If I just pass a function, the click event gets fired and everything works:

```
<IconButton
       onTouchTap={onObjectClick}
       style={iconButtonStyle} >
          <img alt={customer.name} className="object-img" src={object.avatarSrc} />
    </IconButton>
```

However, the function runs with an `event` passed, which does not help me. I need to instead pass an object with data in it. Does anyone know how to set a function that returns a function, or a handler to onTouchTap or an onClick event in react using typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass arguments to `onTouchTap` you need to pass an arrow function and call the function with the desired arguments, like so:

```
<IconButton
   onTouchTap={() => onObjectClick(object)}
   style={iconButtonStyle} >
      <img alt={customer.name} className="object-img" src={object.avatarSrc} />
</IconButton>
```

The reason for this is because `onTouchTap` and other properties like it take a function *object*, not a function *call*. By doing this you're passing an anonymous function (the arrow function) that calls your function with the desired arguments.

Comment: Be aware that if you define the function inside `render()`, it'll get recreated every time the component re-renders. A lot of the time this isn't a problem, but if a component is re-rendering often it can cause performance issues. If you run into this issue, define the function as a class property instead (e.g. `this.onTouchTap = () => onObjectClick(object)`, then `onTouchTap={this.onTouchTap}`)

Comment: @JoeClay I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the input.

Comment: No problem :) It gets mentioned at the bottom of the [docs page on handling events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html), but it's so brief that I think most people miss it.